# parent child conditional statements scraping websites with python and selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape product reviews from a website using python3 and selenium chromedriver.

Embedded in these reviews are company responses (remove these). These company responses are easily identifiable because the title of the content is always "response from company x".

So I'd like a python3 function along the lines of:

```
if 'response from company x' not in mydriver.find_element_by_class_name('bv_content_title').text:
    search for child classes of ('bv_content_core')
    append child class ('bv_content_review_text') to list
```

I'm having trouble using parent child relationships as related to "class" in the HTML. Should I name the parent ('bv_content_core'), then search through all child classes of core to string match? Is there an easier way using XPath parent/childs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are after I presume list.

```
if 'response from company x' not in mydriver.find_element_by_class_name('bv_content_title').text:
    mylist=mydriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.bv_content_core .bv_content_review_text')
    print(mylist)
```

Or try second one.

```
if 'response from company x' not in mydriver.find_element_by_class_name('bv_content_title').text:
    parent=mydriver.find_element_by_css_selector('.bv_content_core')
    mylist=[]
    for child in parent.find_elements_by_css_selector('.bv_content_review_text'):
         mylist.append(child.text)
```